# Control the width of the dividing strip in ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How can I control the width of the dividing strip between the panels in the border layout in ExtJs?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use splitter then you can just set margin. Eg. if you have north and east component then set margin on east component to `'0 0 0 5'`.

If you use split, then you can change splitter size after render.

Working samples:

- with split: http://jsfiddle.net/8Zesp/4/
- without split: http://jsfiddle.net/8Zesp/3/

Answer (score 0):

Or use event "add"

```
listeners: {
    add: function (me, item) {
        if (item.xtype == 'bordersplitter') item.width = 2;
    }
},
```

Demo here http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-border-layout-splitter-width